# Comparing enum constants to string without valueOf or toString?

Tags: java, enums

I have any enum in which I have defined some constants

```
public enum MyEnum{
    MY_CONSTANT1,
    MY_CONSTANT2
}
```

Now am comparing  a string to one of the enum constants in following way-

```
String myVariable ="MY_CONSTANT1";
System. out.println(MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT1.toString().equals(myVariable));
```

The above  returns true  which is understandable.

Now when I do the below----

```
String myVariable ="MY_CONSTANT1";
System.out.println(MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT1.equals(myVariable));
```

The above code returns false. Why is it so?

Comment: Because you are comparing objects of different types. `MY_CONSTANT1` is instance of `MyEnum` type, and `myVariable` is `String`. Why should these be equal?

Comment: BTW, while `toString()` works in this case, it is better to use method designed to return name of enum value which is `name()`. So you should use `MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT1.name().equals(myVariable)`, or if by any chance your goal is to find enum with specified name you can use `MyEnum.valueOf(myVariable)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Okay I got confused . I thought enum constant internally get complied to strings .So I thought comparison should have been fine ..Looks like that's not the case .. enum constants have the type of the enum

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) the javadoc for enum's `equals()` method and this is what it says:

```
public final boolean equals(Object other)
```

> Returns true if the specified object is equal to this enum constant.

Now, if we look into the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java#Enum.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) of `equals()`, this is what it does:

```
public final boolean More ...equals(Object other) {
     return this==other;
}
```

As we can see, it merely checks whether two references are pointing to the same object or not. As the two references in question are different, it returns `false`.

Comment: Okay I got confused . I thought enum constant internally get complied to strings .So I thought comparison should have been fine ..Looks like that's not the case .. enum constants have the type of the enum

Comment: Nope, `enum` does not get compiled to `String`, `enum` is separate type and it stays as `enum` even after compilation.

Comment: @user2713255 just to be clear, in general `enum NameOfEnum{...}` is just syntactic sugar which after compilation will be replaced with `final class NameOfEnum{...}` and its constants will be `public static final NameOfEnum FIELD_NAME = new NameOfEnum();` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the first comparison you are calling toString method of an Enum type, which by default returns the name of the enum:

```
System.out.println(MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT1.toString().equals(myVariable));
```

So, MyEnum.MY_CONSTANT1.toString() is "MY_CONSTANT1". Then "MY_CONSTANT1" equals "MY_CONSTANT1", which is true.

On the other hand, the second comparison is between a Enum type and a String type. The Enum equals function performs the following code:

```
public final boolean equals(Object other) {
        return this==other;
}
```

So, it does not equal, because **other** is a **String** and **this** is a **Enum**.